# MAP Expectation Maximization for mixture models

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, expectation-maximization

I am trying to write down the MAP updates for the EM in case of mixtures of Bernoulli distributions.

I know that for ML estimates, we have:

```
E-step: compute P(Z|X,p,t)
M-Step: (p,t)<-argmax sum(over Z): p(Z|X,p,t)log p(X,Z|p,t)
```

where p are the vectors parameters for each class (K of them, each of size D, where K is the number of classes and D is the number of features) and t are the multinomial parameters for each class.

But how do I get MAP estimates? What would p(X) be...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin P. Murphy page 350:

In the M step, we optimize the Q function (auxiliary function) with respect to theta:

```
theta^t = argmax_theta Q(theta,theta^{t-1})
```

which is the ML, and to perform MAP estimation instead we modify the M step as follows

```
theta^t = argmax_theta Q(theta,theta^{t-1})+log(p(theta))
```

theta is the parameters and theta^{t-1} is the previous approximation of the parameters and theta^t is the current.

Where Q is

```
Q(theta,theta^{t-1}) = E[logL(theta)|Data,theta^{t-1}]
```

The E step remains unchanged

So basically the difference between the ML and MAP is that you add log(p(theta)) inside argmax which is the log prior of your parameters.

For a specific example where the prior p(theta) is beta(alpha,beta) distributed I can refer to the last assignment answer here: [assignment](https://github.com/Jim-Holmstroem/dd2447/blob/master/homework/assignment2/doc.pdf?raw=true)

It should be straight forward to to use your prior or leave it at a general prior.